# error debug visual studio Error "del ..\..\..\..\bin\Debug\Examples.Browser_*.zip >nul 2>&1" exited with code 1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to run a project and keep receiving this error message:

```
"del ..\..\..\..\bin\Debug\Examples.Browser_*.zip >nul 2>&1" exited with code 1
```

How to get rid of this error and get the project to work?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve] .. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 1 generally means that a pre-build or post-build command encountered an error, often related to an invalid path.

Assuming this is command is running as a pre/post-build command, ensure the path is correct. Consider using a macro to make the path relative to a well-known location, such as $(ProjectDir) or $(TargetDir). If a path can contain spaces, it should be quoted.

The following may work for you, depending on your exact directory structure

```
del "$(TargetDir)\Examples.Browser_*.zip" > null 2>&1
```

Comment: This is a dump question, but what file does the change go in?

Comment: Right-click your project in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, click Properties, click the Build Events tab and you should see the existing command as either a pre-build or post-build event.